# Upload .xls file on PHP server using the HTML5 File API

Tags: php, javascript, html, file-upload

I all,

I'm trying to upload an xls file using the HTML5 API.

I already have a script which is working great for images.

It's also working with an xls file except the fact that I can't open the file using excel once it has been uploaded...
If I compare the size, the orignal file is 251 904 octets while the upload one is 251 911 octets. I don't know if that matter.

Here is what i've done :

Javascript:

```
reader = new FileReader();                  
reader.onloadend = function(evt) { 
  that.file = evt.target.result; 
};

reader.readAsDataURL(file); // I've also try with readAsText but it's worse
```

the file is send using Sproutcore Framework:

```
SC.Request.postUrl(url).json()
  .notify(this, 'fileUploadDidComplete', fileName)
  .send({ fileName: fileName, file: file });
```

PHP:

```
$httpContent = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$json = stream_get_contents($httpContent);
fclose($httpContent);

$data = json_decode($json, true);

$file = base64_decode($data['file']);

$fileName = substr(md5(time().rand()), 0, 10).$data['fileName'];
$filePath = GX_PATH."/files/tmp/".$fileName;
$handle = fopen($filePath, "w");
fwrite ($handle, $file);
fclose($handle);
```

I hope somebody will help me to find what is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I find another way which work on more browsers. I've discover FormData !

```
formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);
SC.Request.postUrl(url).notify(this, 'formDataDidPost').send(formData);
```

This way, the PHP code is more simple :

```
$_FILES['file'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using following method

```
$out = fopen($fileUploadPath ,"wb");
$in = fopen("php://input", "rb");
stream_copy_to_stream($in,$out);
```

This is just 3 methods I used to write the uploaded content to the server. Try it and see